# Restrict Microsoft Graph API permissions

Tags: python-3.x, azure, microsoft-graph-api

When running the following code snippet logged in as a simple user i expose my entire organisation emails etc.
I'd like to restrict what a regular user can get from the Microsoft Graph API (i.e only see the logged in user).

```
import os
from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient

credential = InteractiveBrowserCredential()

client = GraphClient(credential=credential)
result = client.get('/users')
print(result.json())
```

Thanks for your help
Cheers
T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Practice is to Stick with least privilege permissions to the users:
[image]

Here is the document for restricting the member users' default permissions:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#restrict-member-users-default-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Being able to view other users' profiles is part of a member user's default permissions (see [What are the default user permissions in Azure Active Directory?](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions)). This capability is used by many of Microsoft's own apps and services (e.g. the address book in Outlook, searching for a user to share a file with in OneDrive for Business or SharePoint, seeing the contact card of a user in Teams, etc.).

While you *can* [restrict member users' default permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#restrict-member-users-default-permissions) and disallow them from reading other user's profiles, this will often cause unexpected and issues with many Microsoft services, and it is generally not recommended.